# COleControl's OnClose is overridden, but never been fired

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I'm writing an ActiveX control for a web page using MFC. When the explorer is closing, some resource need to be released BEFORE the control's main window being destroyed. I did some search and found that an overridden `COleControl::OnClose(DWORD dwSaveOption)` function should be a good place to do the releasing job. So I did the following changes to my code:

1. Add the following line to my control's declaration in the header file:

   ```
   virtual void OnClose(DWORD dwSaveOption);
   ```
2. Add the following lines to my control's implement file:

   ```
   void MyControl::OnClose(DWORD dwSaveOption)
   {
       // some code that do relesing job
       COleControl::OnClose(dwSaveOption);
   }
   ```

I think that when closing the explorer, MyControl::OnClose should being executed, but it's not. Did I miss anything to correctly override the function or OnClose function is not the right place to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I personally override `COleControl::OnDestroy()` for cleanup.  Are you missing some kind of event sink registration call to enable the Close?  Or a dispatch map entry?